# Adding Claims to an ASP.Net Identity Core user fails with EF insert error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

I am using ASP.Net Core on .Net Core, version:

```
> dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  5e8add2190

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.16299
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.5
  Build    : 17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54
```

I am attempting to add a new user with claims using:

```
var r = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser { UserName = "example", Email = "example@example.com" }, "password");
var u = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("example@example.com");

if(u == null) {
    throw new Exception("User was not found");
}

await _userManager.AddClaimAsync(u, new Claim("FullName", "Example McExample"));
```

I am using MS SQL as the backing store, with the schema created by Entity Framework using the command:

```
dotnet ef database update
```

The user is created in the database, but the claim creation fails with the error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'Id', table 'IdentityDemoDatabase.dbo.AspNetUserClaims'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> The statement has been terminated.

When stepping through the code, the user is successfully created, then the user is successfully retrieved (user returned matches user just added) and then the `AddClaimAsync()` method fails with the above error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, I was using the wrong EF migrations.

EF uses the database context you configure in your `Startup` class, and the migrations it generates are very specific to the provider configured there.

I was using the migrations copied from the `dotnet new --auth individual` template, but these are built for Sqlite, not MS SQL Server as I was using.

To generate your own, delete the existing migrations, then configure your `Startup` to use the provider you want:

```
// Add a store context for ASP.Net Identity 2 to use
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));
```

Then add the EF tooling (if it isnt already in your project) to your `csproj`:

`<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.1" />`

Then run:

```
dotnet restore
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

EF will run your `Startup`, get the provider and context and then create the tables in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This saved me a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

> Delete the existing migrations

Use

```
dotnet ef database update 0
```

and

```
dotnet ef migrations remove
```